# os.popen and writing in terminal differ

Tags: python, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am writing a template to stress test my programs.
Where is a file `gen.py` (it was intended to be a test creator):

```
print(1)
```

If I write in Linux terminal `python3 gen.py > test.txt` - python prints `1` to the file.

Where is also a file `stress.py` (this file initially should run the main program many times).

```
import os
os.popen('python3 gen.py > test.txt')
print(*os.popen('cat test.txt').readlines())
```

The result is expected to be "1", but nothing is in the output or in the file `test.txt`. I am running Linux Ubuntu using WSL on windows. Maybe it affects something.

Comment: `os.popen()` merely starts a process.  You didn't wait for the first one to complete before the second one tried to read its output.

Comment: Yes, now it worked. How can I wait till a previous popen finishes?

Comment: `os.popen()` isn't really appropriate when you aren't supplying input or expecting output from the command.  `os.system()` would work better here for the first command (it doesn't return until the command is done), but the best options are found in the `subprocess` module - you can avoid running a useless (and insecure) shell, and can provide parameters without worrying if they contain any characters that would need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do so - you should write `os.popen(...).read()`. That way `.read()` will wait until the function finishes.